# Excel/Google Sheet, changing only one criteria in an entire column

Tags: excel, formula, sumifs

I need some help, and I am quite desperate.

I have this formula in Google sheet and Excel:

=SUMIFS('Data_UCDP-Internal'!C:C,'Data_UCDP-Internal'!B:B,"Afghanistan",'Data_UCDP-Internal'!A:A,**">0")**.

Is there a way to change the last criteria (only) for an entire column? For example, if i wanted to change it to ("=2014"), is it possible to apply that to an entire column instead of doing it manually for each single cell? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, you could simply do a find and replace. Select the range containing the cells that you would like to change. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and type `>1` into the "Find What" textbox, and `=2014` into the "Replace With" textbox. See below:

[image]